# Algorithm for detecting misspelled entities

Tags: r

I have a list of city names that are misspelled by users in a text entry box field for example (Chiqago, Neww jork or also Niu yorc, etc). I would like to know if R can solve this kind of problem that receive a badly written city and transforms into a correct city name.

```
Input city : Chiqago, Neww jork, Niu yorc, St Fransis
Output city: Chicago, New York, New York, San Francisco
```

Comment: one quick way, i.e., minimize mahalanobis (or similar) distance on a known correct "dictionary", might do the trick for easy cases

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into the `stringr` package. You can use `str_detect` to find the incorrect pattern and `str_replace` or `str_replace_all` to replace it with the correct pattern.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html